# NuxtJs append query param on every route navigation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a query string that I need to append to every route so that when I click a link it grabs the querystring and appends it to the URL. This way when I do something like to="route" it will automatically append my querystring to the URL.

I have go this working when I do a single click, however when I double click anything it blows up on me with the following error

> "TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
> Array, or array-like object".

I also see this error in my console every time, just not on the page, so I imagine I am not doing something correctly.

In my `default.vue` page I have the following:

```html
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    // all the components I am using on this page
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      landingRoute: '',
    }
  },
  fetch() {
    if (this.isEmpty(this.$route.query)) {
      const landingKey = this.landingRoute
      this.$router.push({
        name: this.$router.name,
        query: { info: landingKey },
      })
    }
  },

  watch: {
    '$route.query': '$fetch',
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.landingRoute = this.$route.query.info
  },

  methods: {
    isEmpty(json) {
      return Object.keys(json).length === 0
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The error happens in the client.js the stack trace looks like this....

```
"TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object".
  at fromObject (index.js?b639:139)
  at from (index.js?b639:137)
  at Function.Buffer.from (index.js?b639:149)
  at eval (sessionLog.js?d88f:14)
  at promisfiy (utils.js?ebed:291)
  at middlewareSeries (utils.jseed:291)
  at Vue.callMiddlewear (client.js?06a0:267)
  at Vue._calle6$ (client.js05a0:267)
  at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294)
```

Here is my sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-vuetify-forked-wrs2s?file=/layouts/default.vue

Comment: I fixed some errors with my edit. Not sure if it helps anyhow. What you shared is a `layout` right? From here is coming the error that you've just linked?

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is just the layout page. It includes the <nuxt /> tag that each of my pages navigate to, and yes that's where my error seems to be happening.

Comment: Hm, "seems" is not enough here. You need to either give us the exact place from the stacktrace or give us a [repro].

Comment: Not sure how much it helps but I edited to add the stacktrace in the console.

Comment: Yeah, a [repro] will be the fastest way I guess. Your issue is probably because of some type missmatch. It may come from some `index` file or elsewhere. Faster to make a reproduction to find out where is your issue located IMO.

Comment: I added a sandbox. the initial default always has a ?info=xyz on it as that is being passed in from my reverse proxy server, the problem I hit is when I try to navigate to other pages without that ?info on it, it blows up, so I'm trying to grab the ?info and force it onto every route.